# Type-safe composition of maps in C++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, return-type-deduction

I want to write a type-safe function in C++ that composes an arbitrary number of maps. I approached by writing a helper function `point` that computes the application of the composition at a point–

```cpp
template <typename K>
const K& point(const K& k) {
  return k;  // recursive base-case.
}

template<typename K, typename V, typename ... Ts>
auto point(const K& k, const std::map<K, V>& map, Ts... maps) {
  return point(map.at(k), maps...);
}
```

which makes the logic of `compose` straightforward:

```cpp
template <typename K, typename V, typename ... Ts>
auto compose(const std::map<K, V>& map, Ts... maps) {

  using U = typename std::result_of<point(V, Ts...)>::type;  // <- problem

  std::map<K, U> composition;
  for (const auto& [k, v] : map)
    composition[k] = point(v, maps...);
  return composition;
}
```

My only issue is deducing `U`, the value-type of the resulting map . I am sure that `std::result_of` is an appropriate approach, but I get `error: 'V' does not refer to a value` with the code above. I also tried using `decltype(point<V, Ts...>())` but that gives `error: no matching function for call to 'point'`.

Example usage:

```
std::map<int, std::string> m1;
m1[0] = "a";
m1[1] = "b";
 
std::map<std::string, float> m2;
m2["a"] = 3.0;
m2["c"] = 4.0;
 
std::map<float, std::string> m3;
m3[3.0] = "three";
m3[4.0] = "four";

auto composition = compose(m1, m2, m3);
```

Comment: Isn't the return value of "point" always going to be "const K&"? If so you could avoid that problematic line.

Comment: No `point` is a templated function and it's return type depends on it's template arguments.

Comment: I think you can get it to work using `using U = decltype(point(std::declval<V>(), std::decval<Ts>()...));` instead

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver, that works! It would have taken me an extremely long time to figure that out...

Comment: Remember also to declare the recursion ground case **before** the recursive version of `point()`.

Comment: Aah, thanks @max66 for the reminder. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final version using the type deduction provided by @NathanOliver and using `std::optional` to omit any element that cannot be fully mapped through the composition.

```cpp
template<typename K>
const K& point(const K& k) { return k; }

template<typename K, typename V, typename ... Ts>
auto point(const K &k, const std::map<K, V>& map, Ts... maps) {
  return map.find(k) == map.end() ?
    std::nullopt :
    std::optional(point(map.at(k), maps...));
}

template<typename K, typename V, typename ... Ts>
auto compose(const std::map<K, V>& map, Ts... maps) {
  using U = typename decltype(point(std::declval<V>(), std::declval<Ts>()...))::value_type;
  std::map<K, U> composition;
  for (const auto& [k, v] : map) {
    auto result = point(v, maps...);
    if (result.has_value())
      composition[k] = result.value();
  }
  return composition;
}
```

Comment: a little simplification: instead of `std::declval<Ts>()...`, inside `decltype()`, you can write `maps...`.

Comment: another unrequested suggestion: don't mix names of types and values: maybe works but is error prone. I mean: don't name `map` a value; especially when if of type `map`.